# How to highlight one word for each group of words?

Tags: javascript

**Situation:**
I have a text for pupils. Within the text are on different locations three words. All the time, when the three words appear in the text, one of the words has to be highlighted by clicking on it.

Following code allows me to do that:

```
var words = $(document.getElementById("test1")).first().text().split(/\s+/);
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$(document.getElementById("test1")).html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
let highlighted;
$("span").on("click", function() {
  $(highlighted).css("background-color", "");
  $(this).css("background-color", "CornflowerBlue ");
  highlighted = this;

var wort = highlighted.innerHTML


  input1.value = wort;
});
```

**edit html:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  style="font-size: 20px">
lots of text... <b><div id="test1" >[word1, word2, word3]</div></b> more text. <b><div id="test2" >[word1, word2, word3]</div></b>
```

**Problem:**
The first group of words is not a problem with the code above. For the second group of words I would use the same code with ID "test2". When I click on a word of the second group, the mark of the first group disappears as well.

**Question:** 
How can I use the code for multipe ID's, without deleting the mark from the previous ID?
(that I have one mark for each group of words)

Comment: What's your ([mcve]) html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution for you in VanillaJS

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

// wrap in  IIFE
// @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression
void function(d,w) {
  // className of the divs to check
  const className = 'click-react';
  // className to give to highlighted spans
  const highlightClassName = 'click-highlight'
  
  // In every div ...
  Array.from(d.getElementsByClassName(className)).forEach(el => {
    // split text content by whitespace into words
    const words = el.innerText.split(/\s+/);
    // wrap each word with a span tag (with data attribute)
    const wordsMapped = words.map(i => `<span data-click>${i}</span>`)
    // overwrite div with those spans
    el.innerHTML = wordsMapped.join(' ');
  })
  
  // delegate click to document
  d.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // guard conditions:
    // only with correct data attribute
    if (!e.target.hasAttribute('data-click')) {return false}
    // only if inside div
    if (!e.target.closest(`.${className}`)) {return false}
    
    // get currently highlighted span in parent div of the clicked upon span
    Array.from(e.target.closest(`.${className}`).getElementsByClassName(highlightClassName))
      // remove the hightlighted class
      .forEach(el => el.classList.remove(highlightClassName))
      
    // highlight clicked upn span
    e.target.classList.add(highlightClassName)  
  })
  
}(document, window);
```

```css
span.click-highlight {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="click-react">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe doloremque provident fuga possimus eum, ratione libero sapiente, inventore blanditiis nobis est tempora totam? Neque sequi asperiores animi fugiat ducimus. Quidem?</div>

<div class="click-react">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error esse obcaecati alias temporibus placeat? Nesciunt aliquam fugiat perspiciatis doloremque voluptatum excepturi aliquid quam dolore qui quos? Natus dicta vero eius, a optio enim nisi, temporibus harum, non quo recusandae molestias?</div>
<div class="click-react">Tempora totam, dolorem unde consectetur maxime rem nesciunt perferendis soluta dolores earum blanditiis excepturi perspiciatis eaque magnam sint praesentium id dicta laborum quibusdam vel eligendi modi quod odio magni. Tempore aperiam eaque consequatur perspiciatis odit quasi doloribus facere nostrum nesciunt?</div>
<div class="click-react">Pariatur omnis consequuntur quae id, ducimus iste. Quos aliquid maiores totam quo animi voluptatem sed dolores fugit, minima, earum natus voluptas velit pariatur dolore voluptate. Mollitia a ratione facere quisquam voluptate, debitis at officia facilis exercitationem minima, similique magnam dolor.</div>
<div class="click-react">Nihil nulla facilis, odit, saepe tempore, voluptate nemo quod nam ullam corrupti magni! Veritatis soluta officiis rerum, distinctio iste dignissimos numquam. Quaerat deserunt voluptatum beatae accusamus perspiciatis, nemo non magni ut, assumenda similique quae? Similique maiores debitis quod id dolor.</div>
```

Comment: I added some comments

Comment: One additional question. Is it possible to save the word which has been clicked on, like in my example, e.g. var wort = highlighted.innerHTML

Comment: @InPanic `let word = el.target.innerText`

Comment: sorry for all the questions, but either I do something wrong or  `let word = el.target.innerText` does not seem to work. When I use `let word = e.target.innerText;` instead, I can save the Word of the second group in my database, but not the first one (probably it overwrites the first part). Could you maybe clarify where I have to use `let word = el.target.innerText`? (js is not really my thing...)

Comment: @InPanic Lock at this pen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/abzbBMp?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

You could select every div that contains three words (in this example I'm assuming they each have a class of `test-<NUMBER>`. After selecting, just add a class to the highlighted span, and select it according to the current div:

```
var words = $("class^=test-");
words.each(function() {
  const self = this;
  let innerWords = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
  const text = innerWords.join("</span> <span>");
  $(this).html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
  $(this).find("span").on("click", function() {
    $(self).find(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
    $(this).addClass("highlighted");
    const word = $(this).html();
    input1.value = word;
  })
})
```

Add a css class:

```
.highlighted {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}
```

jQuery's [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method is what does the magic here.